# Plotting XY coordinates obtained from Google Maps

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, google-maps, wgs84, nad83

I know how to plot XY coords in ArcMap—right click the table, plot XY, select geographic coordinate system (coords are in degrees), etc. My question is rather when selecting the GCS I always go with my standard GCS which is NAD 83. However, the more I think about it—should I actually use WGS 84 since the coordinates were obtained from Google Maps? I plotted the coordinates both ways and it ends up plotting in the same spot, but im not sure if this would be the case all the time. **I also did not receive a prompt to transform the layer into my documents GCS of NAD83

Comment: You should always choose the the coordinate system that correspond to your data coordinate (so yes for google map it should be WGS84).  Some reading on the difference between WGS84 and NAD83 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Datum#Comparing_NAD_83_to_WGS_84

Comment: If the cords are WGS84, the GCS  should be WGS84, but there isn't much difference (now) especially for CONUS.

Comment: @Vince We've talked about this before! CONUS NAD83 2011 and WGS84 (current realization) are 1-2 m offset. However, the Google Maps coordinates may not be accurate enough for that to matter.